# decode a mp4 video with gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer, h.264, video-processing, decoding, x264

I want to play a mp4 video in Gstreamer, but i got an error with the x264dec which is not found. I wrote this pipeline

```
  gst-launch filesrc \
     location=/media/thesis/Gstreamer/pub_Irma.mp4 \
   ! qtdemux name=demux demux. ! queue ! faad \
   ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demuxer. \
   ! queue ! x264dec ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

After this step, my aim is to generate execution traces of a mp4 video decoding. 
I don't know where is the problem with x264dec.

Comment: you use `name=demux`, but later `demuxer. ! ...`, shouldn't that be `demux.` too?

Comment: @Wimmel you are right, it's just a typing error. The problem with x264dec is always there

Comment: I'm interested about what you will observe in this traces. Is It possible to observe all h264 decoding steps?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think there's a `x264dec` element (I only know of the `x264enc` element). You might want to use `ffdec_h264` like in [this nabble post](http://gstreamer-devel.966125.n4.nabble.com/how-to-play-h-264-file-using-gstreamer-tp971171p971172.html):

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=$1 ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! deinterlace ! xvimagesink
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, i had finally uses this pipelie `GST_DEBUG=qtdemux:5,faad:5,ffdec_h264:5 gst-launch filesrc location=/media/thesis/Gstreamer/pub_Irma.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demuxer demuxer. ! queue ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demuxer. ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink 2> >(tee /media/thesis/Gstreamer/log_pub.csv)
` to obtain an execution trace. i used qtdemux instead of h264parse

Answer (score 13):

This might be easier:

```
gst-launch-0.10 playbin2 uri=file:///path/to/foo.mp4
```

or

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=file:///path/to/foo.mp4
```

(You still need the required elements installed of course).

Comment: Sometimes there is a constraint for the people to not use the playbin2, when they want to R&D. This is what SO is about, sharing our research !

Answer (score 8):

I have a file name tuhi.mp4 in desktop. So the command goes this way.

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=~/Desktop/tuhi.mp4 ! decodebin name=dec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink dec. ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! alsasink
```

Comment: This is totally the way then and now.

Comment: Note that the "dec." after "autovideosink" means "what follows is a data flow branch that begins in parallel with "videoconvert", using data from the element named "dec" (which is decodebin). autovideosink has no source (output) terminal; no data flows out of it to "audioconvert", but this notation is used to represent a data flow branch on one console line.

Answer (score 3):

This command

```
gst-launch-0.10 filesrc location=/root/gstreamerexamples/big.mp4 ! qtdemux name=demux demux. ! queue ! faad ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink demux. ! queue ! ffdec_h264 ! ffmpegcolorspace ! autovideosink
```

works fine for me.

To play mp4 file take bigBuckBunny mp4 video as test file. Next please sure all the elements mentioned in the gst-launch is built in the x86 or any other target platform.

Please send lot of time in correct installation of GStreamer.

Comment: Use gst-launch-1.0 instead, videoconvert instead of ffmpegcolorspace, and avdec_h264 instead of ffdec_h264.

Answer (score 1):

```
    #include <gst/gst.h>

    typedef struct _CustomData {
    GstElement *pipeline;
    GstElement *source;
    GstElement *demuxer;
    GstElement *audioqueue;
    GstElement *videoqueue;
    GstElement *audio_decoder;
    GstElement *video_decoder;
    GstElement *video_convert;
    GstElement *audio_convert;
    GstElement *video_sink;
    GstElement *audio_sink;
    } CustomData;


    static void pad_added_handler (GstElement *src, GstPad *pad, CustomData *data);

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    CustomData data;
    GstBus *bus;
    GstMessage *msg;
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    gboolean terminate = FALSE;
    /* Initialize GStreamer */
    gst_init (&argc, &argv);
    /* Create the elements */
    data.source = gst_element_factory_make ("filesrc", "source");
    data.demuxer = gst_element_factory_make ("oggdemux", "demuxer");
    data.audioqueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue","audioqueue");
    data.videoqueue = gst_element_factory_make("queue","videoqueue");
    data.audio_decoder = gst_element_factory_make ("vorbisdec", "audio_decoder");
    data.audio_convert = gst_element_factory_make ("audioconvert", "audio_convert");
    data.audio_sink = gst_element_factory_make ("autoaudiosink", "audio_sink");
    data.video_decoder = gst_element_factory_make("theoradec","video_decoder");
    data.video_convert = gst_element_factory_make("ffmpegcolorspace","video_convert");
    data.video_sink = gst_element_factory_make("autovideosink","video_sink");

    data.pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");
    if (!data.pipeline || !data.source || !data.demuxer || !data.audioqueue ||!data.audio_decoder ||!data.audio_convert ||
    !data.audio_sink || !data.videoqueue || !data.video_decoder || !data.video_convert || !data.video_sink) {
    g_printerr ("Not all elements could be created.\n");
    return -1;
    }

    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (data.pipeline), data.source,data.demuxer,data.audioqueue,data.audio_decoder,data.audio_convert,data.audio_sink,data.videoqueue,data.video_decoder,data.video_convert,data.video_sink, NULL);

    if (!gst_element_link(data.source,data.demuxer)) {
    g_printerr ("Elements could not be linked.\n");
    gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
    return -1;
    } 

    if (!gst_element_link_many (data.audioqueue,data.audio_decoder,data.audio_convert, data.audio_sink,NULL)) {
    g_printerr (" audio Elements could not be linked.\n");
    gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
    return -1;
    }
    if (!gst_element_link_many(data.videoqueue,data.video_decoder,data.video_convert, data.video_sink,NULL)) {
    g_printerr("video Elements could not be linked.\n");
    gst_object_unref(data.pipeline);
    return -1;
    } 
    /* Set the file to play */
    g_object_set (data.source, "location", argv[1], NULL);

    g_signal_connect (data.demuxer, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK (pad_added_handler), &data);
    /* Start playing */
    ret = gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE) {
    g_printerr ("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
    gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
    return -1;
    }
    /* Listen to the bus */
    bus = gst_element_get_bus (data.pipeline);
    do {
    msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
    GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED | GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

    if (msg != NULL) {
    GError *err;
    gchar *debug_info;
    switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE (msg)) {
    case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
    gst_message_parse_error (msg, &err, &debug_info);
    g_printerr ("Error received from element %s: %s\n", GST_OBJECT_NAME (msg->src), err->message);
    g_printerr ("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info : "none");
    g_clear_error (&err);
    g_free (debug_info);
    terminate = TRUE;
    break;
    case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
    g_print ("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
    terminate = TRUE;
    break;
    case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:

    if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC (msg) == GST_OBJECT (data.pipeline)) {
    GstState old_state, new_state, pending_state;
    gst_message_parse_state_changed (msg, &old_state, &new_state, &pending_state);
    g_print ("Pipeline state changed from %s to %s:\n",
    gst_element_state_get_name (old_state), gst_element_state_get_name (new_state));
    }
    break;
    default:

    g_printerr ("Unexpected message received.\n");
    break;
    }
    gst_message_unref (msg);
    }
    } while (!terminate); 

    gst_object_unref (bus);
    gst_element_set_state (data.pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref (data.pipeline);
    return 0;
    }

    /* This function will be called by the pad-added signal */
    static void pad_added_handler (GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, CustomData *data) {
    g_print("Inside the pad_added_handler method \n");
    GstPad *sink_pad_audio = gst_element_get_static_pad (data->audioqueue, "sink");
    GstPad *sink_pad_video = gst_element_get_static_pad (data->videoqueue, "sink");

    GstPadLinkReturn ret;
    GstCaps *new_pad_caps = NULL;
    GstStructure *new_pad_struct = NULL;
    const gchar *new_pad_type = NULL;
    g_print ("Received new pad '%s' from '%s':\n", GST_PAD_NAME (new_pad), GST_ELEMENT_NAME (src));



    new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_caps (new_pad);
    new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure (new_pad_caps, 0);
    new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name (new_pad_struct);


    if (g_str_has_prefix (new_pad_type,"audio/x-vorbis" /*"audio/mpeg"*/)) 
    {
      ret = gst_pad_link (new_pad, sink_pad_audio);
      if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED (ret)) 
       { 
        g_print (" Type is '%s' but link failed.\n", new_pad_type);
       } 
       else 
      {
        g_print (" Link succeeded (type '%s').\n", new_pad_type);
      }
    } 



    else if (g_str_has_prefix (new_pad_type, "video/x-theora"/*"video/x-h264"*/)) 
    {
      ret = gst_pad_link (new_pad, sink_pad_video);

      if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED (ret)) 
      {
        g_print (" Type is '%s' but link failed.\n", new_pad_type);
      } 
      else 
      {
        g_print (" Link succeeded (type '%s').\n", new_pad_type);
      }
    } 


    else {
    g_print (" It has type '%s' which is not raw audio. Ignoring.\n", new_pad_type);
    goto exit;
    }
    exit:
    if (new_pad_caps != NULL)
    gst_caps_unref (new_pad_caps);
    gst_object_unref (sink_pad_audio);
    gst_object_unref (sink_pad_video);
    }
```

Comment: this is for ogg files, not mp4s

Answer (score 0):

I have a ogg file in my desktop so the command goes this way.

```
$ gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location=~/Desktop/test.ogg ! oggdemux name=demuxer \
    demuxer. ! queue ! vorbisdec ! audioconvert ! audioresample ! autoaudiosink \
    demuxer. ! queue ! theoradec ! videoconvert ! autovideosink
```

This will also work for gstreamer 0.10 but yoy need to replace videoconvert with ffmpegcolorspace