# How to build a pipeline for a MP4 file using Gstreamer?

Tags: gstreamer

I am trying to build a Gstreamer pipeline for MP4 file applications. However, I am unable to do complete pipeline. I did some research online, but some answers are very old like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13500893/decode-a-mp4-video-with-gstreamer)

Here is what I tried.

1. I am creating following elements

```
    filesrc = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "input-file-source");
    demux = gst_element_factory_make("qtdemux", "demux-input-video");
    h264_decode = gst_element_factory_make("avdec_h264", "h-264-decode-video");
    sink = gst_element_factory_make("xvimagesink", "video-sink");
```

2. Adding them to `bin` using `gst_bin_add_many`
3. Linked `filesrc` and `demux` using `gst_element_link_many`
4. Added a `pad-added` signal

```
    g_signal_connect(demux, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(pad_added_handler), demux);
```

5. Set the `pipeline` to running state.

However, I am not getting output.

Also, I don't want to use `playbin` or `decodebin` as it won't allow customization and I won't be learning how to build pipeline for different file formats.

Can someone help on,

1. Whether choice of my elements are correct.
2. Anything I am missing in constructing the pipeline.

Comment: You may try adding element h264parse before decoder and element videoconvert after. You would also have to set elements' properties such as location for filesrc, etc... and maybe set caps for linking some elements. Try with `gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=test.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink`, once working look at caps between elements.

Comment: @SeB It is working. Thank you.. 
I will convert above into C code...

Answer (score 0):

Based on @SeB comment, I created a pipeline and which is working.

```
#include <gst/gst.h>
#include <glib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
    gst-launch-1.0 -v filesrc location=g51.mp4 ! qtdemux ! h264parse ! avdec_h264 ! queue ! videoconvert ! xvimagesink
*/

/* Handler for the pad-added signal */
static void pad_added_handler(GstElement *src, GstPad *pad, GstElement *data);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    GstElement *pipeline, *filesrc , *demux, *h264_parse, *h264_decode, *raw_queue, *raw_v_convert, *sink;
    GstStateChangeReturn ret;
    GstBus *bus;
    GstMessage *msg;
    gboolean terminate = FALSE;

    /* Initialize Gstreamer */
    gst_init (&argc, &argv);
    g_print ("Gstreamer initialization complete\n");

    filesrc = gst_element_factory_make("filesrc", "input-file-source");
    demux = gst_element_factory_make("qtdemux", "demux-input-video");
    h264_parse = gst_element_factory_make("h264parse", "h264_parse");
    h264_decode = gst_element_factory_make("avdec_h264", "h-264-decode-video");
    raw_queue = gst_element_factory_make("queue", "raw-queue");
    raw_v_convert = gst_element_factory_make("videoconvert", "video-convert");
    sink = gst_element_factory_make("xvimagesink", "video-sink");
    

    if (!filesrc || !demux || !h264_parse || !h264_decode || \
        !raw_queue || !raw_v_convert || !sink)
    {
        g_printerr ("Not all elements got created !\n");
    }
    
    g_object_set(G_OBJECT(filesrc), "location", argv[1], NULL);

    /* Create the empty pipeline */
    pipeline = gst_pipeline_new ("test-pipeline");
    if (!pipeline)
    {
        g_printerr ("Pipeline bin didn't create successfully!\n");
    }

    /* Adding elements */
    gst_bin_add_many (GST_BIN (pipeline), filesrc, demux, h264_parse, h264_decode, \
                        raw_queue, raw_v_convert, sink, NULL);

    if (gst_element_link_many(filesrc, demux, NULL) != TRUE)
    {
        g_printerr ("Pipeline linking-1 failed!!\n");
    }

    if (gst_element_link_many(h264_parse, h264_decode, raw_queue, raw_v_convert, sink, NULL) != TRUE)
    {
        g_printerr ("Pipeline linking-2 failed!!\n");
    } 

    /* Connect to the pad-added signal */
    g_signal_connect(demux, "pad-added", G_CALLBACK(pad_added_handler), h264_parse);

    ret = gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);
    if (ret == GST_STATE_CHANGE_FAILURE)
    {
        g_printerr("Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state.\n");
        gst_object_unref(pipeline);
        return -1;
    }

    bus = gst_element_get_bus(pipeline);
    do
    {
        msg = gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered(bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
                                         GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED | GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

        /* Parse message */
        if (msg != NULL)
        {
            GError *err;
            gchar *debug_info;

            switch (GST_MESSAGE_TYPE(msg))
            {
            case GST_MESSAGE_ERROR:
                gst_message_parse_error(msg, &err, &debug_info);
                g_printerr("Error received from element %s: %s\n",
                           GST_OBJECT_NAME(msg->src), err->message);
                g_printerr("Debugging information: %s\n", debug_info ? debug_info
                                                                     : "none");
                g_clear_error(&err);
                g_free(debug_info);
                terminate = TRUE;
                break;
            case GST_MESSAGE_EOS:
                g_print("End-Of-Stream reached.\n");
                terminate = TRUE;
                break;
            case GST_MESSAGE_STATE_CHANGED:
                /* We are only interested in state-changed messages from the
                pipeline */
                if (GST_MESSAGE_SRC(msg) == GST_OBJECT(pipeline))
                {
                    GstState old_state, new_state, pending_state;
                    gst_message_parse_state_changed(msg, &old_state, &new_state,
                                                    &pending_state);
                    g_print("Pipeline state changed from %s to %s:\n",
                            gst_element_state_get_name(old_state),
                            gst_element_state_get_name(new_state));
                }
                break;
            default:
                /* We should not reach here */
                g_printerr("Unexpected message received.\n");
                break;
            }
            gst_message_unref(msg);
        }
    } while (!terminate);

    /* Free resources */
    gst_object_unref(bus);
    gst_element_set_state(pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
    gst_object_unref(pipeline);
    return 0;
}


/* This function will be called by the pad-added signal */
static void pad_added_handler(GstElement *src, GstPad *new_pad, GstElement *h264_parse)
{

    GstPad *sink_pad = NULL;
    GstCaps *new_pad_caps = NULL;
    GstStructure *new_pad_struct = NULL;
    const gchar *new_pad_type = NULL;
    GstPadLinkReturn ret;

    g_print("Received new pad '%s' from '%s':\n", GST_PAD_NAME(new_pad), \
            GST_ELEMENT_NAME(src));

    
    new_pad_caps = gst_pad_get_current_caps(new_pad);
    new_pad_struct = gst_caps_get_structure(new_pad_caps, 0);
    new_pad_type = gst_structure_get_name(new_pad_struct);

    if (g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "audio/mpeg"))
    {
        g_print("init audio GstPad\n");
        sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(h264_parse, "sink");
    }
    else if (g_str_has_prefix(new_pad_type, "video/x-h264"))
    {
        g_print("init video GstPad\n");
        sink_pad = gst_element_get_static_pad(h264_parse, "sink");
    }
    else
    {
        g_print("It has type '%s' which is not raw audio or video. Ignoring.\n",
                new_pad_type);
        goto exit;
    }
    /* If our converter is already linked, we have nothing to do here */
    if (gst_pad_is_linked(sink_pad))
    {
        g_print("We are already linked. Ignoring.\n");
        goto exit;
    }

    /* Attempt the link */
    ret = gst_pad_link(new_pad, sink_pad);
    if (GST_PAD_LINK_FAILED(ret))
    {
        g_print("Type is '%s' but link failed for reason '%i'.\n",
                new_pad_type, ret);
    }
    else
    {
        g_print("Link succeeded (type '%s').\n", new_pad_type);
    }



exit:
    g_print ("Reached exit \n\n");
    /* Unreference the new pad's caps, if we got them */
    if (new_pad_caps != NULL)
        gst_caps_unref(new_pad_caps);

    /* Unreference the sink pad */
    gst_object_unref(sink_pad);
    
}
```